# In Openedx Based Project, Xblock customization need to add CKEditor in textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, openedx

In Openedx Based Project, Xblock customization needs to add CKEditor in textarea in javascript. i am using this xblock "edx-sga Staff Graded Assignment XBlock" need to add one textarea in as a richtext-editor like CKEditor. i am try to do this things and i am facing this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'dir')
at Object.d (3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3Am100%2Bm2021%2B2021m%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4001dda54a2f4a45bc8d827549634e2135:7214)
at y (3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3Am100%2Bm2021%2B2021m%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4001dda54a2f4a45bc8d827549634e2135:7215)
at Array.z (3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3Am100%2Bm2021%2B2021m%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4001dda54a2f4a45bc8d827549634e2135:7215)
at x (3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3Am100%2Bm2021%2B2021m%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4001dda54a2f4a45bc8d827549634e2135:7215)
at HTMLScriptElement.C.CKEDITOR.env.ie.f.$.onerror (3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3Am100%2Bm2021%2B2021m%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4001dda54a2f4a45bc8d827549634e2135:7216)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Upload CDN file openedx based projects in xblock things then follow this thing.

```
       fragment = Fragment()
       fragment.add_javascript_url("https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js")
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3' );

       <textarea name="editor3" id="editor3" rows="10" cols="90"></textarea>
```